# TWO jquery jqModal popup windows on same page via onClick and onLoad?  Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, popup, jqmodal

I am using jquery jqModal script for TWO popup windows:

```
<div id="dialog"></div>  // load via onClick
<div id="success"></div> // load via onLoad
```

I have one html page with two jqModal windows. I would like one to load when the page opens, and another one opens separately via onClick.

My script is not working. The onLoad works (#success), but the onClick (#dialog) opens BOTH up at the same time.

Here is my current script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#dialog').jqm(); 
$('#success').jqm().jqmShow({});
});
</script>
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the updated code you can try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dialog').jqm( {trigger:'#dialog'} ); 
    // $('#dialog').jqmAddTrigger('#dialog'); 
    $('#success').jqm().jqmShow({});
});
```

Let me know if its working for you